# How does Woobox create facebook apps automatically?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

It is said you cannot create apps automatically with the current facebook API.

[Create and Configure Facebook Apps via API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7726219/create-and-configure-facebook-apps-via-api)

[How to programatically create a Facebook application via JS SDK or Open Graph API? (createApplication)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4719260)

Yet woobox.com does it.
I have created a few photo contests in their portal. It didn't ask for extra permission. No dialogs showed up. I just got these links:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/-/105892812908965?sk=app_422118604517529&app_data=dlt-1
http://www.facebook.com/pages/-/105892812908965?sk=app_451684954848385&app_data=dlt-1

How did they create these apps?

> app_422118604517529
>   app_451684954848385

I would expect

> www.facebook.com/pages/-/105892812908965?sk=app_SAME_APP_ID&app_data=WOOBOX_ID_1
>   www.facebook.com/pages/-/105892812908965?sk=app_SAME_APP_ID&app_data=WOOBOX_ID_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with the presumptions that Facebook apps/users/groups and pages can't be created dynamically. What woo box is what many other page tab applications are doing. They create a number of applications for different templates and then customize them according to your inputs. They don't create apps dynamically. And these dynamic apps get their required data from app_data field.
Another point to note is

> An app can't be installed on a page twice

that is why many Service provider that provide page tab applications maintain a pool of applications to fulfill their user's desires.

Comment: I'd expect /105892812908965?sk=app_SAMEID&app_data=dlt-WOOBOX_ID_1 and /105892812908965?sk=app_SAMEID&app_data=WOOBOX_ID_2

Comment: An app can't be installed twice on a page as per the current restrictions. That is why when you added second page tab woobox checked if one of their application is already installed and installed another application with different app ID